# Import models to TensorflowJs

Tags: javascript, import, model, tensorflow.js

```js
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const model = tf.sequential();

const saveResult = model.save('file:/naive_bayes.pkl');
```

I want to import a model tp TensorflowJs which I trained by Python. But I got this error:

```
(node:12312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find any save handlers for URL 'file:/naive_bayes.pkl'
```

I don't get it, I am following its document. https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load?hl=vi

I put all files (model, js) at the same folder.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use like this**

```
const modelDir = 'model' // model floder in same dir

const modelPath = `file://${modelDir}`;

model.save(modelPath);
```

**or simply,**

```
const modelDir = 'model' 

model.save(`file://${modelDir}`);
```